# Improper integral convergence - how to estimate

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I am trying to establish the convergence of the following integral: $$ \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{e^x \sin(x+3)}{\log\vert 2+x \vert} dx $$
I will annotate $\mathcal{U(x_0)}$ when studying the function in the neighborhood of $x_0$

This is what I found:
$$ Dom f(x) = (-\infty,-3) \cup (-3,-1) \cup (-1,+\infty)$$
For the interests of the exercise the function is continuos between $ (-\infty,-3) \cup (-3,-1) \cup (-1,0] $

I first notice that in $\mathcal{U(-1)}$ the function is $$ f(x) \sim \frac{C}{\log\vert 1+x+1\vert} \sim \frac{1}{\vert x+1 \vert}$$ therefore not convergent.

Convergence in $\mathcal{U(-3)}$ is also pretty straightforward.

Now I'm having some trouble for $\mathcal{U(-\infty)}$ ; following aid from the book I took the exercise from I tried to estimate it $$ \vert f(x) \vert \le \frac{e^x}{\log \vert x+2\vert} $$ Now the book suggests that it is also $$ \le \frac{1}{x^2} $$ and I can't really understand how it got there.

I suppose it used hierarchies of infinities but I never really developed a good understanding of how to use them in $\mathcal{U(0)}$ and $\mathcal{U(\infty)}$ , are there some tips you could give me?

Comment: There are two singular points $-2$ and $-\infty.$ At $-\infty $ the function is bounded by $e^x$, so the integral $(-\infty, -3)$ is convergent. Near $-2$ the function behaves like constant times $(\log|x+2|)^{-1}$ so the integral on $ (-3,0)$ is convergent. I do not like the book suggestion as the convergence of $\int _{-\infty}^0 e^x\,dx $ can be performed by the FTC.

Comment: As $x\to-\infty$, $\frac{x^2e^x}{\log|x+2|}$tends to $0$ hence becomes $\le1.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc uh yes I seem to have forgotten the singular point at -2. Would you be able to elaborate/ what it means that the function at $- \infty$ is bounded by $e^x$ ?

Comment: @AnneBauval ok understood. Any tips on how to come up with such estimates? Because without the book's suggestion I wouldn't have found it probably.

Comment: Sorry. I have made a mistake. The singular point are $-1$.and $-3$ There is no problem at $-2$ as $\log|x+2|$ tends to $-\infty$ when $x$ tends to $-2.$

Comment: We have ${|\sin(x+3)|e^x\over \log|x+2|}\le {e^x\over \log 2}$ for $x\le -4.$ So the integral over $(-\infty,-4]$ is absolutely convergent as the integral if $e^x$ is convergent. The latter follows from FTC is we know the antiderivative of $e^x$

Comment: The (very usual) comparison with $\frac1{x^2}$ is the first thing to try when you want to prove that a function is integrable at $\pm\infty.$ (When it does not work, the next one is comparison with $\frac1{x^\alpha}$ for some convenient $\alpha>1$ (smaller than $2$).

Comment: alright thanks for the clarifications! @RyszardSzwarc

Comment: and also @AnneBauval